# Получение ответа после POST запроса

Tags: c#

```
System.Net.WebRequest reqPOST = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(@"http://site.ru/send.php");
reqPOST.Method = "POST"; 
reqPOST.Timeout = 120000; 
reqPOST.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] sentData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes("message=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("отправляемые данные", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)));
reqPOST.ContentLength = sentData.Length;
System.IO.Stream sendStream = reqPOST.GetRequestStream();
sendStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);
sendStream.Close();
System.Net.WebResponse result = reqPOST.GetResponse();
```

Пытаюсь получить ответ от сервера. На который я отправил post запрос.
Но увы, в ответ получаю  System.Net.http.WebResponse

Comment: > Но увы, в ответ получаю System.Net.http.WebResponse

А что же Вы надеетесь получить?

Answer (score 1):

var responseText = new StreamReader(result.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();